# SELECT dates from all years

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a query which looks like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM produit 
WHERE year(date_commande) = '.$date.'
ORDER BY num_serie_produit desc;
```

Where `$date = 2014`.
But this variable can have the value of all, so this means I need to select all product.
I know I can resolve my problem by doing a second query like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM produit 
ORDER BY num_serie_produit desc;
```

But I was wondering if I could use only one query and play with the $date.

I tried something like this :

```
if ($date == "all"){
    $date = '%%';
}
```

but It doesn't change anything :/

So is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this variable can have the value of all,

If `$date == "all"`, then run a different query, without the `WHERE` clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM produit 
        ". ($date == "all" ? "WHERE year(date_commande) = ".$date : "") ."
        ORDER BY num_serie_produit desc;";
```

**My question was "Is it possible with only one query and play with the $date variable ?"**

Kind of. Just construct the query differently (include the `WHERE` clause only if `$date` has a value of "all". This is probably a better way to go about solving your problem, rather than using SQL `IF()` statement, or other ways, imho, because you'd be passing more functions to MySQL when they're not needed, albeit a small "overhead" I think it should be avoided.

Comment: When I say "all" that means I need to selected all the rows wathever the year is. I tried your code it returns me the same numbers of rows.

Comment: Ah, okay! You've not tagged PHP, but I assume you're using PHP, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry I use PHP.

Comment: Yes, this is how I'm doing right now with 2 queries. My question was "Is it possible with only one query and play with the $date variable ?".

Comment: @Booba__2012 Updated answer with an "explanation" to why I chose this way :)

Comment: Nice thanks mate (even if I wanted the other way, Include the "WHERE" only if $date != "all" but I can do that myself ^^ )

Comment: @Booba__2012 Then why didn't you like my answer? :-)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand the answer you proposed to me and there wasn't much explanation. I'm quiete new in mysql/php and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
WHERE "'.$date.'" IN (year(date_commande), "all")
```